# values dot displayed in readonly textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a code below where it displays a text input in one column, the total marks column in the second column and the marks remaining in the last column. The table looks like this below:

```
Marks Per Answer               Total Marks    Marks Remaining
(blank text input)               4              4
(blank text input)               6              6
(blank disabled text input)      4              4
```

But the problem I have is that if the  READONLY text input is empty, it should display a value of the "Total Marks" column (so 4 for the readonly text input in the example above).

Also the readonly text input contains the number of total marks, under the "Marks Remaining" column, this is incorrect, for this row it should display 0. (as for the readonly text input  contains a value of 4 so if we minus that with 4 under Total marks, it should make 0 for Marks Remaining for the disabled text input row.)

So the table should really look like this below when the user accesses the page:

```
Marks Per Answer                                             Total Marks    Marks Remaining
(blank text input)                                                 4              4
(blank text input)                                                 6              6
(readonly text input = 4 (same value as under Total Marks))        4              0
```

My question is that how can both steps above be solved by changing the jquery below:

```
 $(function () {
        //alert("here");         
        var questions = $('#markstbl td[class*="_ans"]').length;

        //disable single entry

        for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){   
        if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").length == 1) {
        //alert(t_marks);
        var t_marks = $("[class*=q" + i + "_ans]");
        var t_marksHtml = t_marks.html();
         t_marks.html("0");
         $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marksHtml).attr('readonly', true);
        //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr('readonly',true);
}                   
}

        //find each question set and add listeners
        for (var i = 0; i <= questions; i++) {
            $('input[class*="q' + i + '"]').keyup(function () {
                var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
                var questionno = cl.substring(cl.indexOf('q') + 1, cl.indexOf('_'));
                var tot_marks = $(".q" + questionno + "_ans_org").val();
                //alert(tot_marks);
                var ans_t = 0;
                $("[class*=q" + questionno + "_mark]").each(function () {
                    var num = (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
                    ans_t += parseInt(num);
                });
                ans_t = tot_marks - ans_t;
                //alert(ans_t);
                //var fixedno = tot_marks;
                var ans = ans_t;
                var answerText = '<strong>' + ans + '</strong>';
                $(".q" + questionno + "_ans").val(ans);
                $(".q" + questionno + "_ans_text").html(answerText);
            });
        }
    });
```

Below is the dynamic HTML table:

```
<form id="Marks" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">


<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
$prev_ques = '';
foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){

?>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <?php
    if($questionId != $prev_ques){
    ?>
    <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?php echo$questionId?> <input type="hidden" name="q<?php echo$questionId?>_ans_org" class="q<?php echo$questionId?>_ans_org" value="<?php echo$searchMarks[$key]?>"><input type="hidden" name="q<?php echo$questionId?>_ans" class="q<?php echo$questionId?>_ans" value="<?php echo$searchMarks[$key]?>"></td>
    <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?php echo$searchQuestionContent[$key]?> </td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?php echo$searchAnswer[$key]?></td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionId?>_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<?php
    if($questionId != $prev_ques){
    ?>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?php echo$totalMarks[$key]?></td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q<?php echo$questionId?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?php echo"<strong>".$searchMarks[$key]."</strong>"?></td>
<?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
$prev_ques = $questionId;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

At the moment in the jquery function I am trying to use the t_marks variable to display the value in the text input but nothing is displayed when I alert t_marks

**UPDATE:**

Complete HTML:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
        <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="2">1 <input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q1_ans" class="q1_ans" value="5"></td>
    <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="2">Here are 2 answers </td>
    <td class="answertd" name="answers[]">B</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="2">5</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="2"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="answertd" name="answers[]">D</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
        <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">2 <input type="hidden" name="q2_ans_org" class="q2_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q2_ans" class="q2_ans" value="5"></td>
    <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="1">Here is a single answer </td>
    <td class="answertd" name="answers[]">True</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q2_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="1">5</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q2_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you include some complete HTML so I can create a fiddle with some real data?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Give me 10 mins to get the html from the view source and I will display it under an `UPDATE` section in my question

Comment: @JamesKleeh I have included the complete html from the view source and included it in the question under the UPDATE section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I THINK this should be all you need:

```
    if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").length == 1) {
        //alert(t_marks);
        var t_marks = $("[class*=q" + i + "_ans]");
        var t_marksHtml = t_marks.html();
        t_marks.html("0");
        $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marksHtml).attr('readonly', true);
        //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr('readonly',true);
    }
```

Comment: Hi James, Ok I included your jquery code into my jquery code in my application and in the question above. Now it does change the "Total Marks Remaining" to 0 for readonly text input rows which is great. But there are 2 little problems. First problem is that if I click on the readonly textbox and press a key, then the number 0 under "Total Marks Remaining" changes back to its original value. The second problem is that it is still not showing the value in the readonly textbox. But you are getting there. Do you have any more ideas? Upvoted answer

Comment: I think I'm missing some HTML. I see a reference to _ans_org, however I don't see that input element anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my fault for not displaying the full html, here is the full html, sorry again

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
$("[class*=q"+questionno+"_mark]").each(function(){
```

searche the class called `q[X]_mark`

and this line

```
<input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionId?>_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
```

write the class this way :

```
q[X]_mark_0
```

i'm not sure if this is your problem, but if it's not right i'll keep looking.

Comment: Hi Charles so are you saying change this line of code `$("[class*=q"+questionno+"_mark]").each(function(){` to `$("[class*=q"+questionno+"_mark]_0").each(function(){`?

Comment: Yeah I have tried it but still no luck, do you have any other ideas?